# Split string with variable number of spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split a string like this:

```
7       300685  1235    200017  200018  200019
```

In

```
7
300685
1235
200017
200018
200019
```

array of strings.

I've come up with this Regex but it keeps the white spaces too:

```
var myStrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(linea, @"\s+");
```

That's because I target any string that preceeds a white space. How to not to do that and keep only not white strings.

I know that it is easily done by removing empty strings from the array but I would like to do it with the regular expression.

Comment: why don't you remove excess spaces before splitting the string?

Comment: why use regex for this? simply use the Split method on the string and remove empty entries. this is more than sufficient than doing a Regex - then you could theoretically just Trim() each item in the array

Comment: How many times this question has already been answered? I can't believe you haven't see the list of similar questions while you typed the title of this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.StringSplitOptions.aspx) enumeration with [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

> The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty
>   string

```
string s = "7       300685  1235    200017  200018  200019";
var array = s.Split(new []{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
7
300685
1235
200017
200018
200019
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/wNjlxt)</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just use `String.Split` method ?

```
var myStrings = linea.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Another way with `Split` and `LINQ` without `RemoveEmptyEntries` option:

```
var myStrings = linea.Split().Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit)).ToArray();
```

Also there is a [`RegexOption.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter that you can pass your `Regex.Split` method to remove whitespaces:

```
var myStrings = Regex.Split(linea, @"\s+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to simply use `string.Split`:

```
string[] s = yourString.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: your first parameter is incorrect.

Comment: `Split` is an instance method.

Comment: @Selman22: I saw that when checking the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why does this not work for you:

```
string str = "7       300685  1235    200017  200018  200019";
str.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can also use [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of white-space characters.

Comment: `Split` is an instance method (non-static).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  string[] splitvalue = string.Split(str, ' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or:

```
  string[] splitvalue = str.Split(null);
```

or:

```
string[] splitvalue = str.Split(new char[0]);
```

Comment: `Split` is non-static (an instance method).

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = "Your String".Split(' ').Where(p =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p));
```